# Tensor reshape error while converting to tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a code where I am trying to convert col into tensor.

Code:

```
feature_columns = {
    "input_ids":
        tf.compat.v1.feature_column.numeric_column(
            "input_ids",
            shape=(512,),
            default_value=0,
            dtype=tf.int64),
}
dense_layer = tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(
    feature_columns=feature_columns.values(),
    name="encoding_layer",
    trainable=False
)

cols_to_tensors = {}
dense_layer(feature_dict, cols_to_output_tensors=cols_to_tensors)
```

`feature_dict` contains key `input_ids` with list of 512 int values.

But while running this code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 512 elements to shape [512,512] (262144 elements) for '{{node encoding_layer_8/input_ids/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](encoding_layer_8/input_ids/Cast, encoding_layer_8/input_ids/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [512,1], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [512,512].
```

Not sure how to fix this as I am not reshaping it to 512x512 matric.